# Дождаться выполнения AJAX запроса и вернуть значение

Tags: javascript, ajax, chrome-extension, promise

Делаю расширение для хрома. Мне нужно из моего файла `content` отправить сообщение на `background` и получить ответ.

Отправляю из `content` так:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type:'test', method: 'getHtml', data: 'test'}, {}, function (response) {
     console.log(response);
});
```

Обработчик сообщений в `background`:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {

        console.log('chrome.runtime.onMessage', request, sender);

        if(request&&request.type&&request.method) {
            sendResponse(window[request.type][request.method](request.data));
        }

    });
```

`getHtml` в `background`:

```
function getHtml (name) {
        // fetch не работает.
        let html = fetch('/html/'+name+'.html').then(function(response) {
            return response.text();
        });
        return html;

        // Promise тоже не работает.
        return $.get('/html/'+name+'.html').then(result => {
           console.log(result);
           return result;
        });
    }
```

В консоль выводятся полученные данные, но в `response` в `content` приходит пустой объект.

Что я не так делаю?

Примеры взяты [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%98%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6) - Не работают

Банально этот пример не работает, а хотя это написано в ответе другого вопроса:

```
function getResult() {
  var q1 = $.get('/html/test.html');

  var q2 = q1.then(function (data) {
    return data;
  });
  console.log('ffffffff');
  return q2;
}
```

По идее сначала должно отработать запрос а потом вывестись консоль. Но происходит наоборот.

Comment: Почему вы догадались написать метод then внутри getHtml - но забыли про существование этого метода внутри addListener?

Comment: @PavelMayorov не совсем пойму. на примере можно?

Comment: @PavelMayorov не работает даже пример с решения с другой темы. Я добавил в шапку.

Comment: "По идее сначала должно отработать запрос а потом вывестись консоль." - нет, сначала - консоль. Код не ждет окончания запроса, а идет дальше.

Comment: @Igor как мне сделать что бы там подождало пока выполнится запрос и вернуть полученные данные?

Comment: ну не работает это так с асинхронными вызовами, смиритесь. Возвращайте `Promise`, a снаружи получайте результат запроса, вызывая `.then`, - внутри функции, которую Вы туда (в `.then`) подадите.

Answer (score 1):

Промисы отлично подходят для этого, вам просто нужно правильно с ними работать.

**background**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {

  console.log('chrome.runtime.onMessage', request, sender);

  if (request && request.type && request.method) {

    window[request.type][request.method](request.data) // вернет Promise
      .then(function (result) { // ожидаем когда промис выполнится
        sendResponse(result); // отвечаем на сообщение
      })
      .catch(function (e) {
        console.log(e); // что-то пошло не так
      })
  }

  return true; // это обязательно: сообщаем onMessage.addListener что ответ будет ассинхронным
});
```

**getHtml**

```
function getHtml (name) {
  return $.get('/html/'+name+'.html');
}
```